# Does OS matter when compiling for iPhone?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, static-libraries

I fairly new on iPhone development and I'm currently trying to add some static libraries to my project but I get the "Symbol(s) not found" error.

I've googled the issue and tried different solutions without any luck. The libraries are compiled on a PC and not on a Mac so my questions are:

Do I need to compile the code on a Mac?
What tool(s) do I need to be able to compile them?

I have included the headers to the project. The code I'm trying to link to are written in c and are compiled for ARM GCC 4.2.

I get the following errorcode:

ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/libbaseapi.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/capseng.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/excodecs.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmautorama.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmclearshot.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmexif.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmextencoder.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmfacewarp.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmfxplugin.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmimageenhance.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmimagefusion.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmjpegsqueeze.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmjpegtools.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmphotoart.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmredaway.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmsemc.a, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /Users/<>/Playground/Collage/fmspeedview.a, file is not of required architecture

Undefined symbols:
  "_caps_destroyBuffer", referenced from:
      -[CollageMainView drawRect:] in CollageMainView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
          "_caps_destroyBuffer", referenced from:
              -[CollageMainView drawRect:] in CollageMainView.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found
        collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build failed (1 error)

BR,
Andreas

Comment: It might help if you post the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add custom (compiled) libraries to an iPhone application. You should always include the source code in your project.

Comment: Well, it IS technically possible, but according to the iPhone developer documentation, it is not allowed.

Comment: Our intensions are not to publish our application on App Store, we're only doing a prof of concept app. 
If it is technically possible as you say, do you know if the libraries shall be compiled on a Mac or if it should work with libraries compiled on a PC? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either add the header files for your libraries to your project,
or if it's a missing framework, add it to the "frameworks" folder in Xcode.

Comment: the libraries are of type *.a are written in c-code and I've included the headers to the project by drag and dropping them into the project.